# Creating a thumbnail from an image already on the server?

Tags: images

I'm trying to generate thumbnails on my server that are being uploaded by a plugin. It uploads all images to a directory. I'm trying to target these files and then create a thumbnail with them based on img_resize, but I am not having any lucky. Eventually I'll be inserting the thumbs into the media gallery and into user meta, but I can't even produce a thumbnail yet, so that is the first task at hand!

Here's my simple code thus far:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/media.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/image.php');

$file = 'http://www.mysite.org/uploads/uploaddir/2012/02/bill.jpeg';

$max_w = 200;
$max_h = 200;
$crop = true;

$filePathInfo = pathinfo($file);
$fileName = $filePathInfo['basename'];

$wpUploadPath = wp_upload_dir();
$destpath = $wpUploadPath['basedir'].'/'.$fileName;

image_resize( $file, $max_w, $max_h, $crop );
```

I tried using the `$destpath` as well and nothing is happening. No thumbnails are being generated. Am I thinking about this incorrectly?

Any light anyone could shed upon this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Tre

SOLVED NOTE: This is the code that finally worked for me. I was using the URI before, to define the image_resize. Not the absolute directory.

```
$wpUploadDir = wp_upload_dir();
$baseDir = $wpUploadDir['basedir'];
$fileName = 'bill.jpg';
$filePath = $baseDir . "/" . $fileName;
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filePath, null);
$attachment = array(
'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
'post_title' => $fileName,
'post_content' => '',
'post_status' => 'inherit'
);
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filePath );

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filePath );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

image_resize($filePath, 200, 200, true, '200x200');
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity is there a reason why you need to store the thumbnails within a separate folder and then convert them to Wordpress attachments? Would it not be easier to upload the images from your plugin using inbuilt Wordpress functionality and save yourself some time? I could be missing the bigger picture here though, just curious. If it helps this link explains how to use the media uploader in a plugin: http://www.webmaster-source.com/2010/01/08/using-the-wordpress-uploader-in-your-plugin-or-theme/ - then just use image sizes for different sized images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, it looks like the file wil be looked for in `.../wp-content/uploads/bill.jpeg`. You'll need to include the yyyy/mm as well. I would use this:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/media.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/image.php');

$file = 'http://www.mysite.org/uploads/uploaddir/2012/02/bill.jpeg';

# Function reference
# image_resize ( $file, $max_w, $max_h, $crop = false, $suffix = null, $dest_path = null, $jpeg_quality = 90 )

$wpUploadPath = wp_upload_dir();
$fileName = preg_replace('/^.*?\/(\d{4})\/(\d\d)\/(.*)$/', $wpUploadPath['basedir'].'/$1/$2/$3', $file);

image_resize( $fileName, 200, 200, true, '200x200' );
```

Give that a whirl and let me know how you make out!

Comment: I changed my wp_upload_dir to be /uploads/ , so it wont be in wp-content. I'll give this a whirl , though

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work. the `$destpath` was `/home/mysite/public_html/uploads/2012/02/bill-poucher-prof2.jpeg` when echoed. I invoked `image_resize( $file, $max_w, $max_h, $crop, '-200x200', $destpath);`. No file was generated :\

Comment: The first parameter is the source, which I left confusing. I'll update my code.

Comment: Hmmm. Still no file is being generated. I wish I knew what was happening :|

Comment: This code does work for me, so you can at least rule out the code itself. That leaves you 3 possible scenarios: (1) you don't have GD installed. Can your server create thumbs on newly uploaded images? (2) The directory `/home/mysite/public_html/uploads/2012/02/` is not writeable. Does your web server have write permissions to that dir? (3) The image is working but it isn't going where you think it's going. image_resize() returns the path to the file it generates, so `echo` that and see what it says. Good luck!

Comment: Hm. I'll have to give it a look. I can upload files via media and get resized images, so I assume I have GD installed. That directory is write-able because the plugin is uploading files to that directory. I've been using a page with a template with that code and just hitting refresh to activate the code to try it. Maybe that's the problem? I'll give it a try with echo, I think I tried it and nothing was returned. I think error reporting is turned off, so I'll turn that back on, give it a go and let you know what happens. Sorry for all the confusion! And thanks for the help!!

Comment: If I don't echo anything, nothing happens. No file is resized, no error is displayed. If I try to echo it, I get `Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-content/themes/sig/movingFiles.php on line 39`

Comment: Well, I somehow made it work. I think it was because I was using the URI for fileName and not the absolute path. I had it generate and insert meta data for the image then resize it, if that matters. I'll post the code above. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you have images on your server that you want to add to WordPress, and then create intermediate Thumbnail sizes:

1. Add them to the WP database as attachment post-types, e.g. via the [Add From Server Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-from-server/).
2. You may then need to have WordPress regenerate intermediate image sizes for those images, e.g. via the [Regenerate Thumbnails Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/).

If we knew what Plugin you're using to upload images, and what the intended use of those images is, we could provide a more precise answer for your use case.

Comment: I'm using gravity forms to handle the file submission. The only problem is gravity forms stores it's files in some odd directory. They have a post-submit-form hook that I want to tap in to, grab the uploaded image, and then re-size it to be used as a users avatar.